# Setting input to SOAP request

Tags: android, ksoap2

I am using SOAP request in  my application,in that my SOAP request structure is as follows:

```
 <Data>
       <Keys>
          <String>
            <V>string</V>
            <K>string</K>
          </String>
          <String>
            <V>string</V>
            <K>string</K>
          </String>
        <Keys>
        <CriteriaKeys>
          <String>
            <V>string</V>
            <K>string</K>
          </String>
          <String>
            <V>string</V>
            <K>string</K>
          </String>
        </CriteriaKeys>
        <No>int</No>
        <Size>int</Size>
      </Data>
```

In this i have problem with setting input to the request.How can i set input for this complex type using addproperty method.Following is my SOAP call code:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);    
            SoapObject authentication = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"authentication"); 

                 Setting property for authentication

                request.addSoapObject(authentication);
               SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            envelope.dotNet=true;
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL); 
            try
            {               
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
                SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse(); 
                Log.i("myApp",result.toString());  
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using native methods/classes of HTTP then there is an easy way set this request in your web call:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
post.setEntity(new StringEntity(yourxmlrequestString, "utf-8"));
```

Comment: Hi Paresh Mayani thanks..But I am new to android i cant understand ur suggestions.I have edited my question with SOAP call code.In that what i have to do.